# No updates to Cortana as the reports suggest

Tags: update, cortana

The [recent article](http://www.wpcentral.com/backend-changes-cortana-suggests-microsoft-update) from [Windows Phone Central](http://www.wpcentral.com) states that there are updates to Cortana. There also was an article in past from the same site suggesting that [Cortana reportedly getting new animations and features with backend update](http://www.wpcentral.com/cortana-reportedly-getting-new-animations-and-features).

**From the recent article**

The changes to Cortana reportedly include all or a few of the following:

- Asking "What is my name?" and having Cortana speak it back
- Importing of your Stock watch list from Bing Finance
- New animations on the Live Tile, including weather icons
- Cortana will verbally respond to select inquiries (not just chitchat)
- Modified layout of news, including dividers between sections and a smaller font
- New quiz option at the bottom of today view to let Cortana learn a bit more about your personal interests/habits.
- New "Give Cortana Feedback" link at the bottom of Cortana's today view.

**Layout modifications**

[image]

Since,

> Microsoft can dynamically update Cortana because the pages generated
>   are in HTML5, meaning there is no need for a software update on the
>   phone.

Then why am I not able to see these updates? Any idea?

Comment: You probably have to install the latest Windows Phone update. The updates not requiring updates are probably smaller updates.

Comment: I do have 8.1 Os

Comment: Have been to Settings and checked for updates?

Comment: Yes. Microsoft can dynamically update Cortana because the pages generated are in HTML5, meaning there is no need for a software update on the phone.

Comment: If MS wants to add new voice commands or new animations to Cortana they have to update the app, since dynamic load will be too costly.

Comment: How will we receive update when the app is not in the store?

Comment: Again: Microsoft can dynamically update Cortana because the pages generated are in HTML5, meaning there is no need for a software update on the phone

Comment: Which build of 8.1 are you on?

Comment: Also, *assuming* they've built Cortana on HTML5 *and* that HTML is generated entirely elsewhere, may lead to a false assumption

Comment: I am using 8.10.12393.890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [recent tweet](https://twitter.com/joebelfiore/status/476623953038151680) Joe Belfiore suggested that Microsoft may be doing some A/B testing, so it may well be that some people are seeing different version whilst they work out which options work best, before firming up options for everyone.